# Tableau - Cannot aggregate a list of IDs

Tags: tableau-api

I am working with a data set where I'm listing a series of account IDs for a given month / year in my data set.  (My month / year are in two different fields - One for year, and one for month.  Every row in the data set has a month, year and an account ID listed.)

I can create a table where I can list the account IDs that correspond to each year and month.  However, very vexingly, I cannot aggregate these IDs using a Count Distinct operation.

When I try to aggregate "Account ID," the row where I'd expect the aggregated account numbers to display is completely blank.  However, if I pull up the raw values, then they populate.

I'm using Tableau Cloud.  I'm new to that, but I used Tableau Desktop for many years, and this is the first time I'm encountering this issue.

If it helps, my data is a live SQL query in Snowflake.

Comment: Can you post some sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a date field (calculated field) using your month and year fields

```
DATE(STR([Month]) + " 1 " + STR([Year]))
```

It's a way of putting together a string that would look like "Mar 1 2016".

After you do this, if you apply COUNT() on your ID field, you should get the correct level of aggregation.